# Unauthenticated error when using Sanctum Token to get API Request with domain URL

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

I am working on a project (web and api) and using Laravel sanctum in my project, I am trying to make an api get request on postman to see user information after logged in but I keep getting this **"message": "Unauthenticated."** error but I **notice** that when I was using the get to access user information from my api on `localhost (http://127.0.0.1:8000/)` it was showing the details and working fine, but when I test it with my `domain url (http://sotun.com/mark/live)` show Unauthenticated.

**My Controller**

```
class AuthApiController extends Controller
{

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'device_name' => 'required',
        ]);
    
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    
        if (! $user || ! Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
            ]);
        }
    
        $token = $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;

        $response = [
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token,
        ];

        return response ($response, 201);
    }
    public function user(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->user();
    }
}
```

**api.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthApiController;

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function() {
    Route::get('/user', [AuthApiController::class, 'user']);
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthApiController::class, 'logout']);
});
```

**User Model**

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'user_id',
        'user_type',
        'user_job',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];  
}
```

In the .env I added the below

**.env**

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAIN=http://sotun.com/mark/live
SESSION_DOMAIN=http://sotun.com/mark/live
```

**postman output**

[image]

[image]

But the same result, please I will help to solve this Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `.env` file configurations to:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="sotun.com,127.0.0.1:8000"
SESSION_DOMAIN=sotun.com
```

*Notice the pluralization of the environmental variable `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS`.*

Comment: Thanks @steven7mwesigwa I have made the changes on my web host cpanel to .env  but I am still getting the same message **"message": "Unauthenticated."** see above postman result.

Comment: @delle [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72658787/edit) and share the **request payload/parameters, cookies and headers** submitted/sent by Postman as well.

Comment: I have share the header image, the cookie is empty, I did not input any parameter just the `Bearer Token` after I login in with this `http://sotun.com/mark/live/login`

Comment: Append to Headers a Referer: http://your-domain-url.